# How to combine my two const in my handle changer in react & filter my array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks for this and when typing it doesn't get its values what I entered and it gets reset. Below one is my handle changer:

```
//handle changer for inputs
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setPerson({ ...person, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

    // an array of non-empty fields
    const fields = Object.entries(person).filter(person => person);
    const state = Object.fromEntries(fields);
    setPerson(state);
    console.log(state);

}
```

I would like to know about a method to get filter my empty values in an array and pass my values to array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, React hook's set state is asynchronous.

If you expect the setState method to be called multiple times per render, use this pattern:

```js
setPerson(person => ({ ...person, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }))
```

Then, this filer: `filter(person => person)` makes no sense, you should use some attribute such as `id` to filter by and if you want only one record, use `find()` instead.

If you want more concrete answer, you should provide the data structure `person` contains.